# Displaying images from URL in android app?

Tags: android, performance, listview, bitmap

I'm trying to make an app that parsers HTML and retrieves images and creates a list of news or posts.

I'm having a problem with displaying images because when i download it its large and when i try to use Bitmap decoding to sample down the size of image the ListClass object Only supports array of Integers(R.id...).

I researched to use InputStream but it only supports Drawable. Is there a way to display the images on my list from the website so it does not allocate much memory that leads to slowing down the app?

**Image for main activity;**

[image]

**My MainActivity;**

```
[![import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {

    ListView list;
    String\[\] web = {
            "asd "};
    Integer\[\] imageId = {
            R.drawable.pol};

    Handler handler;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        listClass adapter = new
                listClass(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web\[+ position\], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

InputStream class i tried to implement;

```
import android.media.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;





public class imageHandler {

    Image picture;


    public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "earthdownload");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Glide library to load images from url Refer here:http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-glide-image-loader-library/

Comment: its always better to use image downloading libraries for developing applications which has extensively deal with bitmaps.If you are using your own mechanism for downloading images from net and try it to show it on listview. surely you will get outofmemory exception.To avoid this exception you have to takecare of cache mechanism,bitmap resizing,and memory allocations.Instead of this simply you go with image downloading libraries.

Comment: BitmapFactory can very well decode and scale down from input stream. So you made yourself a problem.

Comment: @greenapps I understand that i could use BitmapFactory. But it only allows me to createFromStream and returns as a drawable.

Comment: @JagjitSingh Never heard about that library will check it out.

Comment: @Vishwa Just for clarification, these downloading images libraries would already deal with bitmaps without going through my own mechanism?

Comment: @asdff Glide,Volley,Picasso can be used to load images from url

Comment: `it only allows me to createFromStream`. Not true. `and returns as a drawable`. Nonsense. BitmapFactory creates ... Bitmaps.

Comment: You can use blow library for image loading 
- Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso
- Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide
- Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
- AQuery (Android Query)  http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/aquery-image-loading/
- Fresco  https://github.com/facebook/fresco
- Volley https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-example-to-load-image-from-internet/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this also Fix the size according to you..or see the resize with universal loader**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@id/ivImage"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"

android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

**Used the Android Universal Image-Loader**

> Declare

```
    private ImageLoader imageLoader1;
```

> On Create

```
 imageLoader1 = ImageLoader.getInstance();

 imageLoader1.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
```

> no_image here a drawable image without any image load in Cache

```
   DisplayImageOptions
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    imageLoader1.displayImage(yourpath.replace(" ", "%20"), ivImage, options);
```

**You Can Use Piccaso Also and Glide also**